# Controller method not found Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have only this route in routes.php

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

and this is the HomeController.php

```
class HomeController extends \BaseController {

    public function getAboutUs()
    {
        return "About page";
    }

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return "Home page";
    }
}
```

the '/' page is OK but when I try to go /about-us page it returns "controller method not found"

Comment: I tested it and both routes seem to work. Anything else in your routes or any other controllers?

Comment: @stuartthey no, That's all.

Comment: Is your URL currently being rewritten? e.g. http://example.org/public/ instead of http://example.org

Comment: Can you post the output of `php artisan routes`? That will help to debug your problem.

Comment: @lowerends just these 2 routes, nothing more.

Comment: I just installed a fresh Laravel, and the problem fixed. but my last installation was also clean and i didn't change any setting in config or somewhere else.

Comment: Take a look at this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698433/controller-method-not-found-laravel-4

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `about-us` route in your routes.php

```
Route::get('about-us', 'HomeController@getAboutUs');
```

Comment: that's true, but not my answer, the whole point of using ::controller in routes file is that not specifying each routes. and using method getAboutUs() to generate /about-us page automatically.

Comment: did you try `/about_us`?

Comment: yes, as I said above the problem fixed with fresh installation of Laravel. and by the way getSomeNameHere() method will generate a /some-name-here route.