# How to implement Socialite in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I try to implement https://github.com/laravel/socialite at my Laravel 5.1 project.

So as I read at documentation I write:
at services.php

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id'     => '567898789',
        'client_secret' => 'e7055b8576508b4026098d3chhh41d98',
        'redirect'      => 'http://domain.com/login/callback/facebook',
    ],
```

also at app.php I add:

```
    Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

and aliases:

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Now at AuthController I add:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')
         ->scopes(['scope1', 'scope2'])->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

        // $user->token;
    }
```

and route.php:

```
//Social Login
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

But NOW when I try to go at http://domain.com/auth/facebook I get:

[image]

> NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269: Controller method
>   not found.

What is wrong? WHere I make error? Hw to solve this problem?

Comment: I also try to add this : use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

Answer (score 0):

May be it refers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698433/controller-method-not-found-laravel-4)

Try to change order of route registration.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but, you don't seem to have `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`
which causes the Controller to not see the Controller class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Socialite;

class AuthController extends Controller
```